# java interface static final object equality error

Tags: java, class, interface, static, final

I have a problem.
I'm create numeric interface, and I'm create static final object in interface. If I modify the objects and checks the equality, returns true. I overriden the 'equals', the problem is unchanged.

Here is the code:

```
public interface Numeric<T extends Number> extends Cloneable, Comparable<T> {

     public static final Numeric<Short> SHORT = new Numeric<Short>() {

            private short value = (short) 0;

            @override
            public Numeric<Short> add(Short value) {
                               this.value += value;
                               return this; 
            }

            @override
            public Short value() {
                   return value;
            }
     }

     public Numeric<T> add(T value);

     public T value();

     //....
}

public class Test {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Numeric<Short> one = Numeric.SHORT;
        Numeric<Short> two = Numeric.SHORT;
        one.add(Short.MIN_VALUE);
        System.out.println(two.value()); //print -32768!!!!! why not 0?
   }
}
```

Thanks the answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`one` and `two` refer to the same object (`Numeric.SHORT`). When you add `Short.MIN_VALUE` (which is equal to `-32768`) to `one`, you are also adding it to `two`, since they are the same object.

If you want `two` to be unaffected by changes to `one`, then you would have to make a copy of `Numeric.SHORT` for each assignment.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your `SHORT` is static which is treated the same as a singleton.  Both assignments `one` and `two` are pointing to the same reference.

Since you added the shorts min value to "one" it's really modifying the singleton which two points too as well.

Answer (score 0):

You have declared `SHORT`  as `static`, which means **shared copy**.

When you said

```
    Numeric<Short> one = Numeric.SHORT;
    Numeric<Short> two = Numeric.SHORT;
```

Reference `one` and `two` were essentially pointing to **same object** that is `SHORT`. Now `one.add(Short.MIN_VALUE);` changed the value of `SHORT`, which is still pointed by `two`, hence the value `Short.MIN_VALUE` which is `-32768` printed.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined a `static Numeric<Short>` called `SHORT`.

`static` means that there is one instance shared among all implementations of  your `Numeric` interface. Every time you refer to `Numeric.SHORT` you refer to the same instance.

`one` refers to `Numeric.SHORT` and `two` refers to the same `Numeric.SHORT`.

When you call `one.add(Short.MIN_VALUE);` the value of `Numeric.SHORT.value` is now `Short.MIN_VALUE`.

Then you call `two.value()` and since `two` is the same `Numeric.SHORT` instance, it will return `Short.MIN_VALUE` which is -32768